Integral representation of the Hermite Function
I want to derive the following integral representation of the Hermite Function
$H_{\nu }(z)$ where $\Re(\nu )$<1 and $| \arg (z)|$<$\frac{\pi }{2}$
$$H_{\nu }(z)=\frac{2^{\nu +1}
   \int_0^{\infty } e^{-t^2}
   t^{-\nu }
   \left(t^2+z^2\right)^{\nu
   /2} \, dt}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1-\nu
   }{2}\right)}$$
I can show that
$$H_{\nu }(z)=\frac{2^{\nu +1} z
   \int_0^{\infty } e^{-t^2}
   t^{-\nu -1}
   \left(t^2+z^2\right)^{\frac
   {\nu -1}{2}} \, dt}{\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{\nu
   }{2}\right)}$$
I then invoked the recurrence formula for the Hermite functions:
$$H_{\nu }(z)=\frac{H_{\nu
   +1}(z)}{2 z}+\frac{\nu 
   H_{\nu -1}(z)}{z}$$
and arrive at the result $$H_{\nu }(z)=\frac{2^{\nu
   +1}}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1-\nu
   }{2}\right)}
\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t^2}
   t^{-\nu }
   \left(t^2+z^2\right)^{\nu
   /2} \left(-\frac{\nu +1}{2
   t^2}+\frac{\nu }{2
   \left(t^2+z^2\right)}\right
   ) \
 dt$$
Substituting numerical values suggests that the above formula is correct, but is not of the desired form. Any suggestions ?
